# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (111)

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following mysql command:

```
mysql -h 10.8.0.16  -u username -p
```

after typing the password, I receive the following error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (111)

Here's the contents of `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`

```
!bind-address = 0.0.0.0
!server-id               = 1
#!relay-log               = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
!log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
#!binlog_do_db            = newdatabase
!ibinlog-ignore-db = "database"
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Here is the result of my `netstat`

```
$ netstat -an | grep tcp | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57630         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:57630         ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:57628         127.0.0.1:3306          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:57570         127.0.0.1:3306          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:57600         127.0.0.1:3306          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:57594         127.0.0.1:3306          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:57608         127.0.0.1:3306          CLOSE_WAIT
```

Comment: Could you please share what distribition you are using, what version of MySQL you are using, if it's MySQL or MariaDB; also, please run `netstat -nlp |grep 3306`, check the process ID (PID) of the binary listening on that port, and then the output if `ps -AF |grep <PID here>`. And please edit your question to add the new information, don't add it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL is configured to bind only to `127.0.0.1`. Configure bind-address properly:

/etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Don't forget to restart mysqld afterwards.

Comment: Also, your config file looks completely wrong. The only directive that starts with `!` is `!includedir`. I would be surprised if the mysqld starts at all with this config file.

Comment: I will remove `!`

Comment: Hello,

Here are the two lines in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`


When I add `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`, and restart `mysql` using the following command `sudo systemctl restart mysql` the service will not start properly.


However,
If I add `!bind-server 0.0.0.0` and restart the `mysql` server using the same command, the server starts properly, without any errors.

`!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/`
`!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`